# RSpec: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm tackling RSpec error.
Article associates ArticlesArticleSeries. Also ArticlesArticleSeries associates ArticleSeries.
ArticlesArticleSeries has two fk constraint. So the problem occurs when inserting record without ArticleSeries association.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
  1) ArticlesController GET #index assigns all article
     Failure/Error: article = Article.create! valid_attributes

     ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
       Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eiicon`.`articles_article_series`, CONSTRAINT `articles_article_series_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`series_id`) REFERENCES `article_series` (`id`)): INSERT INTO `articles_article_series` (`article_id`, `series_id`, `num`) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eiicon`.`articles_article_series`, CONSTRAINT `articles_article_series_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`series_id`) REFERENCES `article_series` (`id`))
     #   ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My RSpec code is here

```
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      id: 1,
      current_version: 1,
      publish_version: 1,
      thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
      status: "publish",
      publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
      user_id: 1,
      update_user_id: 1,
      article_histories_attributes:[
        version: 1,
        title: "Hello!",
        content: "World!World!!!"
      ],
      articles_article_series_attributes: valid_series_attributes
    }
  }
  let(:valid_series_attributes) {
    {
      article_id: 1,
      series_id: 2,
      num: 3
    }
  }
  let(:valid_aseries_attributes) {
    {
      id: 1, name: "test"
    }
  }

      it 'assigns the article as @article' do
        article_series = ArticleSeries.create! valid_aseries_attributes
        article = Article.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, params: {article: new_article_attributes.merge(new_series_attributes), article_histories: new_history_attributes}, session: valid_session
        expect(assigns(:article)).to eq(article)
      end
```

Comment: Some `series_id` in that code is referencing a `Series` that doesn't exist

Comment: Exactly. I finally found how to solve. I'll update my description. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to solve it.
Append let valuable like this. And then it works.

```
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  login_admin

  let(:user) { @admin }
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:some_article) }
  let(:article_series) { FactoryGirl.create(:article_series) }
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      current_version: 1,
      publish_version: 1,
      thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
      status: "publish",
      publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
      user_id: user.id,
      update_user_id: user.id,
```

Note that yo don't need article_id. It's automatically assigned.